# Error handling in mocha unit tests

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have mocha tests.  I will simplify as possible as I can. 
I wonder how should I handle the errors in mocha tests. For example, if there is an error in getName, what should I do? How can I throw an error? Or should I use `done(error)` as;

```
 it('trial', function(done) {
    getName(function (name, err) {
        if(err){
            done(err); //what should I do here? 
        }else{
            console.log(name);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: always use `done(err)` if you have async code. Throwing things asynchrone won't work.

Answer (score 3):

If `done`is called with a argument other than `undefined`, the test will fail and be reported as such. Other test will still be executed.

It allow you to test for success, but also for error:

```
it('succeed', (done) => {
    myFunc('success', (err, res) => {
        if(err) {
            done(err);
        } else if(res !== 'expected') {
            done('Wrong result ' + res);
        } else {
            done();
        }
    });
});

it('fail with error 404', (done) => {
    myFunc('fail', (err, res) => {
        if(err) {
            if(err === 404) {
                done();
            } else {
                done('Error was expected to be 404, got ' + err);
            }
        } else {
            done('Was expected to fail, got result ' + res + ' and no error');
        }
    });
});

it('succeed', (done) => {
    try {
        var res = myFuncSync('succeed');
    } catch(err) {
        done(err);
    }
    done();
});

it('fail with error 404', (done) => {
    try {
        var res = myFuncSync('succeed');
    } catch(err) {
        if(err === 404) {
            done();
        } else {
            done('Error was expected to be 404, got ' + err);
        }
    }
    done('Was expected to fail, got result ' + res + ' and no error');
});
```